# Read a text file line by line to make multiple plots

Tags: pgfplots, text

I want to read a text file line by line. Each line represents the name of a data set. I want make a plot of each data set. The name is used to refer to file that contains the data and must appear in the caption. Furthermore, the name may contain special characters, e.g. an underscore.

The text file (filetoread.txt) looks like this:

```
SomeDatasetName_1
NextDatasetName_2
...
LastDatasetName_n
```

I use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285451) method to read filetoread.txt line by line. In each iteration I want to create a plot. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
    \newread\file
    \openin\file=filetoread.txt
        \loop\unless\ifeof\file
            \read\file to \fileline % Reads a line of the file into \fileline
            \begin{figure}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[xlabel=XName,ylabel=YName]
                \addplot[no marks] table[x=TheX,y=TheY, col sep=comma] {Data/\fileline.txt};
                \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{figure}
        \repeat
    \closein\file
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following errors:

- Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'Data/SomeDatasetName_1 .tx\' (refer to the pgfplotstable manual for details). \repeat
- Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'Data/NextDatasetName_2 .tx\' (refer to the pgfplotstable manual for details). \repeat
- Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'Data/LastDatasetName_n .tx\' (refer to the pgfplotstable manual for details). \repeat
- Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'Data/\par .txt\' (refer to the pgfplotstable manual for details). \repeat

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I prefer to get this method working since it doesn't require other packages to read the text file. Thanks.

Comment: For the underscore named files, you may need to surround the filename in quotes `"`, as in `{"Data/\fileline.txt"}`.  Additionally, you loop is going one too many times, and is considering the last blank line of the file as a filename.

Comment: The way to deal with the second problem is to test the emptiness of the `\fileline`, as in `\if\relax\fileline\relax\else\begin{figure}...\end{figure}\fi`.

Comment: The 3rd problem is that `\fileline` is inserting an extra space at the end, so that `\fileline.txt` is being evaluated as, for example, `SomeDatasetName_1 .txt`.  Perhaps including the suffix-name directly in the external file (and removing it from the `\addplot` line) would be preferable

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: Thanks, solution works! If I understand correctly, the statement checks if \relax if equal to \fileline, if true it does \relax, if false it plots the figure? What is \relax exactly?

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: I also tried to put the extensions in the text file. This works, however, the list is quite long. Is there any other way to solve this? Remove the space somehow?

Comment: It is good practice not to omit the 2nd `\relax`, however, because if there is something before the `\else`, it will be used for the 2nd token.  Try this: `\def\a{}\if\relax\a\relax T\else F\fi` to see that `\a` need not be defined as `\relax` to yield the true branch.  If you omit the 2nd relax, though, the `T` becomes the 2nd comparison token, and the comparison comes up false.

Comment: I deleted a prior comment of mine, because it was inaccurate.  Let me instead refer you to the TeXbook pp209-210, to better explain all the `\if` style conditionals.  The difference between `\if` which expands the arguments and `\ifx` which at most performs a single expansion (if the arguments are macros) is an important distinction. http://www.ctex.org/documents/shredder/src/texbook.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have actual files to work with, but based on comments with the OP, I am hoping this will work.

Things that were done:

1. Filename surrounded by `"` quotes, to allow for characters like underscores in the data filenames.
2. After `\fileline` is read, a comparison must be made to screen out the last blank line of the name file from being considered as a filename.  Thus, `\if\relax\fileline\relax\else\begin{figure}...\end{figure}\fi` has been added to the logic.
3. To eliminate the space that gets introduced at the end of `\fileline`, the macro `\noblankfileline` is introduced to strip it.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\newcommand\noblankfileline{\expandafter\noblankaux\fileline\relax}
\def\noblankaux#1 \relax{#1}
\begin{document}
    \newread\file
    \openin\file=filetoread.txt
        \loop\unless\ifeof\file
            \read\file to \fileline % Reads a line of the file into \fileline
            \if\relax\fileline\relax\else
            \begin{figure}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[xlabel=XName,ylabel=YName]
                \addplot[no marks] table[x=TheX,y=TheY, col sep=comma] {"Data/\noblankfileline.txt"};
                \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{figure}
            \fi
        \repeat
    \closein\file
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot for your fast and clear answer!

Comment: @J.Adan If that is so, then the way to say thinks is to click the check mark to the left of the *best* answer to your question to "accept" it.  That tells other readers which of the possibly several answers worked best for your situation.  Once you get enough reputation, you will be able to click the up arrow to the left of *any* question or answer that is not your own (called an upvote) to indicate that the question or answer was useful to you.