# Runaway argument? Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete

Tags: graphics

I am having trouble with an image in Latex. I am getting the error message:

```
Runaway argument?
width=8cm][height=8cm]{IMG_0390.PNG} \end {figure}
! Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
```

I have got the graphicx package on the file, my code for the image is;

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=8cm][height=8cm]{IMG_0390.PNG}
\end{figure}
```

There are no other errors in the document and no errors when I cut this part out

The full error message with the display math is:

```
! Missing $ inserted
<inserted text>
                $
l.63 ...aphics[width=8cm,height=8cm]{IMG_0390.PNG}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do `\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=8cm]{IMG_0390.PNG}`.

Comment: That fixed that problem but now it thinks that it needs to insert begin/end math symbols

Comment: Then show us the code that's causing this issue. I doubt it's the `\includegraphics` which wants to have begin/end math.

Comment: note that almost always you should not  specify both height and width, just specify one of them or the image will scale by different amounts in each direction and be distorted.

Comment: When it contains *special* characters, such as `_`, put the filename between double quotes, as in `{"IMG_0390.PNG"}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes why? `\includegraphics` handles `_` just fine. It would be more relevant against spaces.

Comment: @daleif I don't know *why* other than to say that the error message indicates a desire to go into math mode, which would be invoked when a character like `_` is interpreted with a catcode of 8.  The double quote certainly helps in similar areas, such as `\addplot`, if the underscored filename is part of argument, once expanded, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399120/read-a-text-file-line-by-line-to-make-multiple-plots

Comment: The issue here is of course that the `_` is being read in the text, not at part of the argument to `\includegraphics`, in the code provided by the OP, the mandatory argument  read my `\includegraphics` is `[` (because the args are wrong). Since `_` not legal in text, this is the error given.

Comment: I have removed the _ from the image file name and this has fixed the problem thank you all for your help