# File name Invalid character reading from txt file

Tags: eps, includegraphics

Hello following this post [Read a text file line by line to make multiple plots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399120/read-a-text-file-line-by-line-to-make-multiple-plots), I created a latex code to read a file that contains the names of eps files I want to plot.

My code is:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\noblankfileline{\expandafter\noblankaux\fileline\relax}
\def\noblankaux#1 \relax{#1}

\begin{document}
 \newread\file
 \openin\file=accretion.txt
 \loop\unless\ifeof\file
  \read\file to \fileline % Reads a line of the file into \fileline
  \if\relax\fileline\relax\else
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm]{"./pictures/\noblankfileline"}
    \end{figure}
  \fi
 \repeat
 \closein\file
\end{document}
```

and the txt file is something like this:

> run20150131_Sediment_Accretion_Erosion_2015-01-31_23h-30m.eps
>   run20150228_Sediment_Accretion_Erosion_2015-02-28_23h-30m.eps
>   run20150331_Sediment_Accretion_Erosion_2015-03-31_23h-30m.eps
>   run20150430_Sediment_Accretion_Erosion_2015-04-30_23h-30m.eps

When I compile it I obtain this error:

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
<read 1> r 
           u n 2 0 1 5 0 1 3 1 _ S e d i m e n t _ A c c r e t i o n _ E r o...
l.22         \repeat
```

it likes the code doesn't recognise the input from the file as a single word.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?
Thanks!
Ciccio

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) that is not an error I get, I get an error that `\includegraphics` is undefined (you forgot the `grahpicx` package) after loading that as well it just complains that the file is not found

Comment: Better still, redefine `\def\noblankaux#1.#2 \relax{#1}` to remove the suffixes automatically, assuming the filenames only have a single `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

daleif's answer is best, but I thought it worthwhile to explain why your approach failed on compile.  It is an expansion issue.  It would seem that the `\includegraphics` searches the filename in search of a file extension.  The problem is that the search occurs before `\noblankfileline` was expanded, and so no extension is noted.  Then, when `\includegraphics` finally gets around to expanding `\noblankfileline`, it doesn't know what to do with the extension attached to the filename.

The fix provided in the MWE, is to expand `\noblankfilename` in an `\edef` and use that expanded macro as the argument to `\includegraphics`.  Alternately, as I said in an earlier comment, you could modify `\noblankaux` to strip file extensions from the list, since `\includegraphics` will search all valid extensions looking for a fit.  One would do that with the following redefinition: `\def\noblankaux#1.#2 \relax{#1}`.

But as I said, daleif's answer is better for your set of conditions, because you supply the file extension in your list, and therefore a spurious space never appears between the filename and the file extension.  So the whole `\noblankfilename` is not really necessary in your case.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{accretion.txt}
run20150131_Sediment_Accretion_Erosion_2015-01-31_23h-30m.png
%run20150228_Sediment_Accretion_Erosion_2015-02-28_23h-30m.eps
%run20150331_Sediment_Accretion_Erosion_2015-03-31_23h-30m.eps
%run20150430_Sediment_Accretion_Erosion_2015-04-30_23h-30m.eps
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\noblankfileline{\expandafter\noblankaux\fileline\relax}
\def\noblankaux#1 \relax{#1}

\begin{document}
 \newread\file
 \openin\file=accretion.txt
 \loop\unless\ifeof\file
  \read\file to \fileline % Reads a line of the file into \fileline
  \if\relax\fileline\relax\else
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \edef\tmp{./pictures/\noblankfileline}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{\tmp}
    \end{figure}
  \fi
 \repeat
 \closein\file
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes Thanks for the explanation and code! Your solution works after I re-generated the txt file, before not... maybe some strange format.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you need

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{url,graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
 \newread\file
 \openin\file=accretion.txt
 \endlinechar-1%<- this removes the space at the end of each read line
 \loop\unless\ifeof\file
  \read\file to \fileline% Reads a line of the file into \fileline
  \if\relax\fileline\relax\else
   \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm]{\fileline}
    \end{figure} 
  \typeout{X\fileline X}
  \fi
 \repeat
 \closein\file
 \endgroup
\end{document}
```

Mainly I was looking at what is written to the log by `\typeout`

You macro to remove the spaces at the end probably never get expanded

The `\endlinechar-1` was something I found on the site

Comment: Good point, `\includegraphics` can automaTeXly handle underscores in the filename, and since the `accretion.txt` file list already includes the filename suffixes, there is no need to strip the trailing blank.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I think we need to strip the blank at the end, since otherwise it complains that it cannot find `"....eps "` note the space at the end.

Comment: So we are back to `\noblankfileline` are we?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes no my code does not use it, just `\endlinechar`

Comment: I see.  Very clever!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes not that I know what's going on, just that others have solved this issue before, so there got to be some hints somewhere.

Comment: TeXbook, p.48: "If the value of `\endlinechar` is negative or greater than 127, no character is appended, and the effect is as if every line ends with a `%`."

Comment: @StevenBSegletes my copy lives at home....

Comment: @daleif Thank you very much for your answer and the discussion with Steven B. Segletes! It helped me a lot to understand better everything.
I tried your solution, I modified it because the files are in a directory, but I obtain the error "File not found".

Comment: @daleif I modified the txt file putting the whole eps file path and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With `expl3` it's much easier to cope with reading files line by line:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{accretion.txt}
run20150131_Sediment_Accretion_Erosion_2015-01-31_23h-30m.png
run20150228_Sediment_Accretion_Erosion_2015-02-28_23h-30m.png
run20150331_Sediment_Accretion_Erosion_2015-03-31_23h-30m.png
run20150430_Sediment_Accretion_Erosion_2015-04-30_23h-30m.png
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx} % draft because I haven't your files

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\figuresfromfile}{O{}m}
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g_ciccio_figuresfile_ior { #2 }
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_ciccio_figuresfile_ior
   {
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    X{\scriptsize\ttfamily ##1}X\\ % just for debugging
    \includegraphics[#1]{##1}
    \end{figure}
   }
  \ior_close:N \g_ciccio_figuresfile_ior
 }
\ior_new:N \g_ciccio_figuresfile_ior
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\figuresfromfile[width=10cm,height=10cm]{accretion.txt}

\end{document}
```

The `X...X\\` line has been added to show that the file name is absorbed without spaces at either end.

[image]