# How to read a file line by regular expression and extract and evaluate the number contained in the matching line?

Tags: pdftex, auxiliary-files, data-structures

Can [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285451/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-and-store-each-line-into-an-array) be generalized to use some kind of regular expression, not just index, and then extract and evaluate the numbers at the beginning or end of the selected line, using some modifiable arbitrary delimiter (e.g., white space)? Thanks

% Sample outputs:

```
\ReadFile{\myarray}{somefile.txt}

\myarray{text:}{end}[]
11
\myarray{3}{end}[]
11

\myarray{text:}{beginning}[]
NA
\myarray{13}{beginning}[]
NA

\myarray{_top_}{end}[]
NA
\myarray{_top_}{beginning}[]
46 %45+1+0

\myarray{new stuff}{end}[]
NA
\myarray{three}{beginning}[]
93 %90+3+0
```

% Sample latex code `file.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{xparse}
    
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \ior_new:N \g_hringriin_file_stream
    
    \NewDocumentCommand{\ReadFile}{mm}
     {
      \hringriin_read_file:nn { #1 } { #2 }
      \cs_new:Npn #1 ##1
       {
        \str_if_eq:nnTF { ##1 } { * }
          { \seq_count:c { g_hringriin_file_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq } }
          { \seq_item:cn { g_hringriin_file_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq } { ##1 } }
       }
     }
    
    \cs_new_protected:Nn \hringriin_read_file:nn
     {
      \ior_open:Nn \g_hringriin_file_stream { #2 }
      \seq_gclear_new:c { g_hringriin_file_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq }
      \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_hringriin_file_stream
       {
        \seq_gput_right:cx 
         { g_hringriin_file_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq }
         { \tl_trim_spaces:n { ##1 } }
       }
      \ior_close:N \g_hringriin_file_stream
     }
```

% Sample data `somearray.txt`

```
File: file.tex
Encoding: ascii
Words in text: 11
Words in headers: 12
Words outside text (captions, etc.): 13
Number of headers: 31
Number of floats/tables/figures: 32
Number of math inlines: 33
Number of math displayed: 34
Subcounts:
  text+headers+captions (#headers/#floats/#inlines/#displayed)
  45+1+0 (1/0/0/0) _top_
  56+1+0 (1/0/1/0) Section: Beginning
  67+2+0 (1/0/0/0) Section: Main part
  78+5+0 (1/0/1/1) Subsection: Sub part one new stuff
  894+5+0 (1/0/2/0) Subsection: Sub part two old stuff 
  90+3+0 (1/0/0/0) Subsection: Sub part three
  12+1+0 (1/0/0/0) Section: End
```

Comment: While it is possible to do this, I want to warn you: Regular expressions in LaTeX are slow! If possible, use another programming language for your extraction instead, e.g. Perl or Python.

Comment: Hi @Skillmon. Thanks. I was trying to avoid mixing languages for this. But if you have a working solution in Perl, Python, or another viable language, then please kindly share it.

Comment: if that's the full range of line types you don't need regex there just a simple loop splitting on `:` until you get to  `Subcounts` when you can split  on `+` and `/` combinations.

Comment: Hi @David Carlisle. Thanks. A general solution could be great. But a solution that works for the sample data and sample outputs given is also OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You don't need regex here, you can use custom delimited macro arguments to pull apart the line, and use custom macros to access the values.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newread\fl
\openin\fl=somearray.txt

\def\splitlineA#1:#2\relax{%
\def\lastline{#1}%
\ifx\lastline\Subcountstest
\let\splitline\splitlineB
\else
\expandafter\gdef\csname FL-#1\endcsname{#2}%
\fi
}
\def\splitlineB#1+#2+#3 (#4/#5/#6/#7)#8\relax{%
\expandafter\gdef\csname FL-#8\endcsname{{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}}%
}
 
\def\Subcountstest{Subcounts}
{
\catcode`\#=12
\let\splitline\splitlineA
\makeatletter
\endlinechar=-1
\loop
\read\fl to \tmp
\ifx\@empty\tmp
\else
\expandafter\splitline\tmp\relax
\repeat
}

\def\FLval#1{\csname FL-#1\endcsname}
\def\FLsubcount#1#2{%
  \def\tmp##1##2##3##4##5##6##7{###2}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tmp\csname FL- #1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Words in headers} = \FLval{Words in headers}

\textbf{Number of headers} = \FLval{Number of headers}

\textbf{text} in \textbf{Subsection: Sub part three} = \FLsubcount{Subsection: Sub part three}{1}

\textbf{inlines} in \textbf{Subsection: Sub part two old stuff}  = \FLsubcount{Subsection: Sub part two old stuff}{6}



\end{document}
```

---

Version requested in comments that adds up #1+#2+#3 and discards the next 4 numbers

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newread\fl
\openin\fl=somearray.txt

\def\splitlineA#1:#2\relax{%
\def\lastline{#1}%
\ifx\lastline\Subcountstest
\let\splitline\splitlineB
\else
\expandafter\gdef\csname FL-#1\endcsname{#2}%
\fi
}
\def\splitlineB#1+#2+#3 (#4/#5/#6/#7)#8\relax{%
\def\tmpa{#1}\ifx\tmpa\texttest\else
\expandafter\xdef\csname FL-\@firstofone#8\endcsname{\the\numexpr#1+#2+#3}%
\fi
}

\def\texttest{text}
\def\Subcountstest{Subcounts}
{
\catcode`\#=12
\let\splitline\splitlineA
\endlinechar=-1
\loop
\read\fl to \tmp
\ifx\@empty\tmp
\else
\expandafter\splitline\tmp\relax
\repeat
}

\makeatother

\def\FLval#1{\csname FL-#1\endcsname}


\begin{document}

\textbf{Words in headers} = \FLval{Words in headers}

\textbf{Number of headers} = \FLval{Number of headers}

\textbf{Subsection: Sub part three} = \FLval{Subsection: Sub part three}

\textbf{Subsection: Sub part two old stuff}  = \FLval{Subsection: Sub part two old stuff}



\end{document}
```

Comment: @Krantz there are no line numbers here. the second argument is a number between 1 and 7  pulling out one of the 7 fields 1+2+3 4/5/6/7

Comment: @Krantz I'm confused then. You mean the format is not fixed as the 7 numbers `text+headers+captions (#headers/#floats/#inlines/#displayed)` ? what is the general form??? even with a regex answer I would have assumed that those 7 numbers should be pulled out of each line

Comment: Essentially, I mean can we make `\FLsubcount` have a single argument like `\FLval`?

Comment: well yes but what answer do you want back, the whole line not split up on + and / (that would be a lot simpler)

Comment: Hi @David Carliste. Thank you very much. I can take it from here based on what you have provided. I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: @Krantz I did a second version, see upodated answer

Comment: Hi @David Carlisle. It works as expected. Great work. Well done. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @David Carliste. I don't know for certain or why, but the second macro seems to disrupt `pandoc`, while the first seems to disrupt `pandoc` and `biblatex`. These do not work when I input the second and first solutions' macros, respectively. Can you confirm if this is plausible in your opinion or perhaps I am wrong?

Comment: @Krantz i can't see any connection with biblatex, if you give this tex to pandoc and ask it to convert it to something else I would expect it to fail of course, pandoc can't be expected to cope with arbitrary tex commands, just "known" packages.

Comment: Hi @David Carliste. Thank you. I use mostly the second solution. Is there anything that can be done to make the second solution's commands be "known" by pandoc? It does the job but I also need to use pandoc.

Comment: No idea, you'd need to ask on a pandoc forum (I don't have pandoc) but if you are converting from tex to (say) markdown via pandoc, what would you expect this to be converted in to?? The target language has nothing suitable, so you can't really expect the convertor to do anything (but my knowledge of pandoc is sketchy:-) @Krantz